# Understanding of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function

I tried to search for explanation of this JavaScript function. I want to understand how does this function get the value? Could someone please suggest a place where I can read more about passing/using value this way.

```
pie.value = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return value;
    value = _;
    return pie;
};
```

This code is from D3 JS.

Comment: It's impossible to say because `value` is not declared in the code you posted. The symbol `value` *inside* that function is *not* the same as the property name of that `pie` object.

Comment: do you mean [http://underscorejs.org/](http://underscorejs.org/) ?

Comment: What do you mean by "this way"? It's just passing an argument in the normal way. The name of the argument is `_`.

Comment: Ok Now I understood, I didn't see the variables set on top. I thought there is something here about basic javascript which I don't understand. But now I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a getter/setter that relies on a closure.

```
var value = 5; // initial value

var getterSetter = function(newValue) {
  // value is closed from the outer scope
  if (!arguments.length) {
    // CASE A
    return value;
  }
  // // CASE B
  value = newValue;
  return getterSetter;
};

getterSetter()   // arguments.length is 0 (CASE A) so displays value (5)

getterSetter(10) // arguments.length is 1 (CASE B) so values is set to 10

getterSetter()   // now this displays 10 since value now is 10 (CASE A)

console.log(value); // Also displays 10, this is the same value variable
```

Now in CASE B, you can see that getterSetter returns itself. This way it becomes (kind of) *chainable*, which means you can do:

```
getterSetter(1)(2)(3)(); // assign 1 then 2 then 3 and displays 3;
```

Your case is a bit difference as the `pie` object is returned in CASE B,instead of the function pie.value, which means you can do that:

```
pie.value(1).value(2).value(3).value();
```

Comment: Ok Now I understood, I didn't see the variables set on top.